# Installing Crypt::SSLeay on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, perl, openssl, perl-module

When trying to install `Crypt::SSLeay` on Mac OS X I get the following error:

```
$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> install Crypt::SSLeay
Reading '/Users/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 26 Oct 2017 01:53:54 GMT
Running install for module 'Crypt::SSLeay'
Running make for N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/.cpan/sources/authors/id/N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz

Cannot link with any of the requested SSL libraries 'ssl, crypto, ssl32, ssleay32, eay32, libeay32, z'
No 'Makefile' created'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
Failed during this command:
 NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz               : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

I have installed openssl as per the instructions found [here](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/) and the output of `openssl version -a` is:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
compiler: cc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0f/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0f/lib/engines-1.1\"" 
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0f/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0f/lib/engines-1.1"
```

I'm not sure what else I can do, as I have the ssl library required but it doesn't seem to link it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0f/ssl"

This is not a standard location for openssl. Which explains why it cannot find the necessary files:

> Cannot link with any of the requested SSL libraries 'ssl, crypto, ssl32, ssleay32, eay32, libeay32, z'

When looking at the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72/README.md) for Crypt::SSLeay you will find:

> If you have OpenSSL headers and libraries in nonstandard locations, you can use
>        $ perl Makefile.PL --incpath=... --libpath=...

There are further instructions in the README how to set the path when using cpanm etc.

Apart from that, in most cases you don't want to install Crypt::SSLeay but instead Net::SSLeay. Crypt::SSLeay is only supported to keep older versions of LWP working, all newer things (including current versions of LWP) use Net::SSLeay and IO::Socket::SSL on top of Net::SSLeay.

Comment: I don't know much about the modules, but the software I'm using has a `PREREQ_PM` for `Crypt::SSLeay => '0.51'`. Just a bit confused, so I don't install the PM and instead just include the headers and libraries in the `perl` command when running the `Makefile.PL`?

Comment: @Rekovni: there are multiple ways to install Perl files. One is cpan or cpanm and the instructions for use with cpanm are in the README too. Or you can unpack the *.tgz, run `perl Makefile.PL && make test install` in which case the instructions I've cited from the README apply. For more details please read the README, it has this name for a reason.

Comment: And you may run into other issues too, on MacOS do `brew install openssl` to get your needed files to build Net::SSLeay

Answer (score 1):

If this is related to installing `LWP::Protocol::https` , because you wanted to use `LWP::UserAgent` ... you will be bettor off installing: `IO::Socket::SSL` instead off aforementioned `Crypt::SSLeay`

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, in README it's mentioned "--incpath" and "--libpath" to use custom paths to your  openssl instalation.

So it should be something like this (Note:check your openssl version, in this example it's 1.1.1d):

```
$ sudo perl Makefile.PL --incpath="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include" --libpath="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib"
```

I struggled to understand what path should be used on those parameters. Those worked though.